# Modify a wildcard string within two other strings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, wildcard

Assuming I have the following code as the value of a variable (I can use either  JS or PHP for this):

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>The Page Title</h1>

   <img src="MyImage.JPG" class="graphic" />

   <p>Some body copy...</p>

   <img class="graphic" src="misc/SecondImage.JPG" />
</div>
```

Is there a way I can convert the image filenames to lower case whilst preserving the case of everything else, and then rewrite all of the new code into the variable?

If the solution involves finding all instances of `src="*"` (or, anything between the strings `src="` and `"`) and converting them to lower case, that would be fine (I'm happy with the `src` values of any future elements I add being converted as well).

Comment: "rewrite all of the new code into the variable" what this means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP where `$html` is your html content:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$imgNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imgNodeList as $imgNode) {
    $imgNode->setAttribute('src', strtolower($imgNode->getAttribute('src')));
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to apply lowercase on path basement (filename) you can go with `DOM` along with regex:

```
$html = <<< STR
<div class="container">
   <h1>The Page Title</h1>

   <img src="MyImage.JPG" class="graphic" />

   <p>Some body copy...</p>

   <img class="graphic" src="misc/SecondImage.JPG" />
</div>
STR;


$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// Get all images
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $img) {
    $newSrc = preg_replace_callback('~[^/]+$~', function($match) {
        // Convert file names to lowercase
        return strtolower($match[0]);
    }, $img->getAttribute('src'));
    // Set new attribute value
    $img->setAttribute('src', $newSrc);
}

// Save to original variable
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output of `echo $html;`

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>The Page Title</h1>

   <img src="myimage.jpg" class="graphic">

   <p>Some body copy...</p>

   <img class="graphic" src="misc/secondimage.jpg">
</div>
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/F9D31)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```js
$('img').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('src',  $(this).attr('src').toLowerCase())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <h1>The Page Title</h1>

   <img src="MyImage.JPG" class="graphic" />

   <p>Some body copy...</p>

   <img class="graphic" src="misc/SecondImage.JPG" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the code in my original post is the value of a variable, not part of the DOM.

To give more context I'm actually retrieving the HTML from somewhere else and storing it in a variable, and from there I need to make the image filenames lowercase.

Comment: @Chris so the above html is a part of variable ?

Comment: That's right, sorry the code colouring might be working against me here :)

Comment: @Chris then it's better to crearte jsfiddle for stack snippet code to show your code